# Creating and activating a virtual environment using a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, virtualenv

I have this script that creates and activates a virtual environment

```
import os
import platform
import subprocess
import venv

# Determine the user's platform
current_platform = platform.system()

# Define the name of the virtual environment
venv_name = "my_venv"


# Create the virtual environment using EnvBuilder
builder = venv.EnvBuilder(system_site_packages=False, clear=True, symlinks=False, upgrade=False, with_pip=True)
builder.create(venv_name)

# Activate the virtual environment
if current_platform == "Windows":
    activate_path = os.path.join(venv_name, "Scripts", "activate.ps1")
    subprocess.call([f"powershell.exe", f"{activate_path}"])
else:
    activate_path = os.path.join(venv_name, "bin", "activate")
    subprocess.call([f"bash", f"source {activate_path}"])
```

It works on Windows, however the venv does not remain active when the script finishes executing. This means that I cannot access the venv in the terminal, something which is desirable. If I write ".\my_venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1 " then I see that it is activated. Does anybody have a solution to this?

Executed the script, expected that the venv would remain active in terminal which wasn't the case.

Comment: "It works on Windows, however the venv does not remain active when the script finishes executing." of course not, because `subprocess` creates... a subprocess (or something approximating it on Windows... I'm not really sure). Activating an environment in a sub process won't activate it in the parent process